# Gray in navbar, can't find CSS to remove

Tags: wordpress, css, wordpress-theming

I am working on a new theme for a wordpress site, http://hanahanpolice.com/test/ when I hover over the items the background is gray on some. This only happens when I am on the main page (/test) any other page I do not see the gray. I can not find where this color is coming from. Can anyone help?

Comment: What tools did you test with?

Comment: The search found in chrome F12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for this class:

```
.front-page .menu .current_page_item a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    filter: none;
}
```

And remove:

```
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: So I changed this and it is now working on the Home item but the dropdown is still brown/grayish. Should this fix them both?

Answer (score 0):

In your style.css at line 1308 remove background from this class:

```
.front-page .menu .current_page_item a{
}
```

And btw, you can always use for problems like this FireBug for Firefox or with IE developer tools - just press F12.